# Android checking whether a bitmap contain another bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have 3 bitmaps (Bitmap A, Bitmap B and Bitmap C). I added Bitmap B to Bitmap A to form Bitmap C. How can I ensure that Bitmap C contain Bitmap B assuming Bitmap B is at the foreground while Bitmap A is the background? I wanted to check pixels but the height/width of Bitmap C is different from Bitmap B since Bitmap A is larger than Bitmap B.

Edit: The area which the Bitmap B is added into is generated randomly.

[image: Example]

I want to check whether B is within C.

Comment: `I added Bitmap B to Bitmap A to form Bitmap C` this has little sense to me... you cannot "add" any Bitmap to other Bitmap

Comment: Yes. I "draw" Bitmap B ontop Bitmap A using a canvas.

Comment: ok i see it now, so what is your real problem actually?

Comment: After drawing, I want to compare and check whether Bitmap C (the canvas) contain the Bitmap B.

Comment: contain? you mean its bounds?

Comment: `pixels but the height/width of Bitmap C is different from Bitmap B since Bitmap A is larger than Bitmap B.` I wonder why that would be a problem. So you are stating that if they were equal in size you could? But then it would make no sense to draw B on A is it?

Comment: @pskink: yes, its bounds.

Comment: so use `android.graphics.Rect` / `android.graphics.Region` API, or i am missing something, maybe some image describing your issue?

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38619/Finding-a-Bitmap-contained-inside-another-Bitmap

Comment: @pskink. Great link. Nice code!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare pixelwise the region that B occupies in C with the pixels of B. Their values should be equal then.

Comment: I'm thinking of this but is this possible when the region at which B occupies in C is generated randomly but within certain boundary.

Comment: That makes things complicated. I wonder why you did not mention this right away in your post. But you can do a kind of start byte search in the pixel array and then continue.

Comment: So I perform a search for the first few byte of Bitmap B in Bitmap C, calculate the offset and retrieve the pixel for the region using the width and height of Bitmap B?

Comment: About like that. Of course you should use width and height of bitmap B.